# Apply rules to transpose dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],'level_1': ['L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L2FR','L2Date','L2value'], 'val3':['Fasting','11/4/2005',1.33,'Random','18/1/2007',4.63,'Fasting','18/1/2017',8.63]})
```

[image: Image.]

But I would like to have my output dataframe as shown below:

[image: Image.]

Please note that concept_id = 123 indicates "Fasting" and 456 represents "Random". I have this information (keys) in another csv file. How do I link all this?

However, I managed to get till here:

```py
d1 = s1[s1['level_1'].str.contains('Date')]
d2 = s1[~s1['level_1'].str.contains('Date')]


d1['g'] = d1.groupby('person_id').cumcount()
d2['g'] = d2.groupby('person_id').cumcount()

d3 = pd.merge(d1,d2,on=["person_id",'g'],how='left').drop(['g','level_1_x','level_1_y'], axis=1)
```

[image: Image.]

Please note that what I have shown is for a single csv data file and single hash/key file which contains concept_ids. In real time, I have more than 30 csv files and 1 hash/key file.

So the hash file remains the same, but data file changes frequently.

For example, this file had two concepts "Fasting" and "Random" , which could be replaced as 123,456 by looking at the hash file. Similarly other data file might contain terms like "Sick", "Healthy" which should be replaced as 135,579 etc.

But the data format remains the same. Can you help me achieve this?

** Update screenshot for output **

[image]

** Mismatch in group by cum count **

[image]

I am expecting all these values should be of same numbers for each group (ex: 1,1,1 or 10,10,10) based on the number of occurrence the value is. Am I right? But no idea why it is different. Moreover my input dataframe has no NA's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a pivot here. You'll need a little extra work though to specify the columns and index of the pivoted dataframe. Here's one way:

```
g = df.level_1.str[2:]
ix = g.groupby(g).cumcount()
out = (df.pivot_table(values = 'val3', 
               columns= g, 
               index = g.groupby(g).cumcount(), 
               aggfunc='first'))

out['person_id'] = df.loc[ix.groupby(ix).idxmax(), 'person_id'].values

print(out)

level_1       Date       FR value  person_id
0        11/4/2005  Fasting  1.33          1
1        18/1/2007   Random  4.63          2
2        18/1/2017  Fasting  8.63          2
```

---

For the `ConceptID` column, you can just create a dictionary to `map` the values accordingly

Comment: But the person_id column is missing. Can you help me to get that?

Comment: Is there anyother way to get the person_id? and also to identify column? I mean there can be more than 100 columns. For example, it can start from L1date, it can go upto L123date as well. So in this case, str[2:] may not work always

Comment: I see that idxmax(), does the sum. But from the name it looks like, it is going to find the maximum. Any links to read about this?

Comment: Yes, it is just a way to get the first index in each group in `ix`. All values are the same in `person_id` for each group, the index doesnt really matter @AVLES

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I tried your solution. It works fine but for half of the records, it returns Nan's for 'FR' and 'value' column. Can you kind of share some suggestions on what can be the reason to see NA. My ip dataframe is like shown in question

Comment: Is the index = g.groupby(g).cumcount() creating this issue? I see the values for half of the data correctly but rest of the half, I see full of Nan's. Cannot share real data as it's confidential. But the data format/input is same as shown in question. Can you please help?

Comment: Just I was trying to debug. The g.groupby(g).cumcount() - doesn't return the same number of rows for all 3 values (FR, Date & value). For ex - FR returns max cum count value as 102345 whereas Date returns max cum count value as 134567 and value returns max cum count value as 156789 etc. As you can see each of them are more than the other. How can we avoid this?

Comment: Updated the screenshot in post for output

Comment: df.isna().values.any() returns 'False' for my input dataframe. Not sure what's the issue. I guess the issue is happening with g.groupby(g).cumcount()